# MySQL: Insert multiple rows with same AI value

Tags: mysql, innodb, auto-increment

Let's say this is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE tab (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    val VARCHAR(9),
    KEY(id),
    PRIMARY KEY (xx)
);
```

Would it possible to insert multiple rows at the same time in a way that they would all get the same auto-increment value?

The following works, but increments each new row, regardless of the fact that we are doing a single query.

```
INSERT INTO tab (id,val) VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(),'a'), (LAST_INSERT_ID(),'b');
```

How could I make sure they all receive the same auto-incremented ID in a single query?

Comment: That sort of undermines the whole point of auto_increment! If you want rows to share a common id then use something other than an auto-incrementing id to store that. Note that with a MyISAM engine any auto-incrementing only needs to be a component of a PK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to keep the first AI value in a variable and pass it in the INSERT query for different pairs

Comment: Yeah I thought so. Then there is absolutely no other way?