# Inserting a series of numbers as rows in database

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql

Is it possible to insert a series of rows that number off at the same time instead of individually inserting each?

So if I had a table with columns A and B and I wanted 50 rows with column A filled in from 1-50 is it possible to do that all on the same command without writing each number out, individually?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14257683/mysql-insert-multiple-rows-with-same-ai-value

Comment: You can set the columns to be auto incremented.

Comment: Ahhh I see. Sorry, Im kindda new to database. I'll look into that

Comment: Despite its name, auto_increment won't guarantee 'incrementality'. That's not what it's for! And this isn't a duplicate of *that* question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you tagged this with Postgres:

```
insert into some_table (col_a, col_b)
select i, null
from generate_series(1,50) i;
```

More details about `generate_series()` in the manual: 
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-srf.html

Comment: Can you explain what i is

Comment: ohh wait, is it just setting col_a as `i`

Comment: i is an alias for the result of generate series.

Comment: It inserts 50 rows into the table, generated by the function `generate_series()`

Answer (score 1):

You also tagged this with mysql.

If you have a utility table of integers (0-9, and simpler I think than a series of UNIONs) then you can emulate Postgres's clever behaviour as follows:

```
 DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ints;
 CREATE TABLE ints(i INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY);
 INSERT INTO ints VALUES (0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9);

 DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

 CREATE TABLE my_table(a INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,b CHAR(1) NOT NULL);
 INSERT INTO my_table (a,b) SELECT i2.i*10+i1.i+1 n,'x' FROM ints i1 JOIN ints i2 HAVING n <= 50;

 SELECT * FROM my_table;
 +----+---+
 | a  | b |
 +----+---+
 |  1 | x |
 |  2 | x |
 |  3 | x |
 |  4 | x |
 |  5 | x |
 |  6 | x |
 |  7 | x |
 |  8 | x |
 | .. |.. |
 | .. |.. |
 | .. |.. |
 | .. |.. |
 | 46 | x |
 | 47 | x |
 | 48 | x |
 | 49 | x |
 | 50 | x |
 +----+---+
```